# Java updating class member when it is re-created

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

Let's say I have the following code:

```
public Class classA{

private classC objC;
private Properties prop

initializeA(){
//Creating a new objC here
this.objC = new C(this.prop);
}
public void doStuffA(){
    //do something here that uses objC.method()
}
}
```

And my classB is:

```
 public class B{

    @Autowired
    classA objA;

    initializeB(){
    objA.initializeA();

    }

    public void doSomething(){
      //Multiple threads keep calling this method and this code block calls           objA.doStuffA()
       }

    }
```

Now, can anyone please explain what happens when initializeB() is called by a thread when some re-initializing is done?
ClassA would now have a new objC that has updated properties. The multiple threads that are accessing doSomething in classB, do they automatically use the new objC that classA created the second time when it was re-initialized?

PS: Is this solved using volatile variable, if yes how?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this and suggested a close please comment as to why you think this question is not relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok given the following:

1) Assuming an instance of classA is created and autowired into B

2) Multiple threads are repeated calling doSomething which is using classA's current instance of classC

3) During the "iterations of step 2"  someone calls initializeB()  when this is called Object A's instance of classC is replaced with a new instance of classC.  This drops the old reference to the previous instance of classC.

At this point in time if a thread was in the process of your old instance of classC's object it will finish its execution using the old instance.  However, all future calls to doSomething will use the new instance of classC.

Do they automatically use the new objC that classA created the second time when it was re-initialized?

```
Yes
```

PS: Is this solved by using volatile variable, if yes how?

```
I am not seeing an issue with this code other than some poor programming practices.
```

If you don't mind my asking what are you trying to accomplish?  There is probably a much better way to do this.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find this anywhere. I would be interested in knowing what are the poor programming choices here. For background, classA was created by me, while classB is a part of an Application that someone else created for me. classB extends some logic from the Application and calls my classA that is supposed to be handling the sending of the data part. ClassC is a third party library.

Comment: While your code is perfectly functional it leaves quite a few potential dangerous practices.  For example you have potential for shared mutability with the current threading setup.  Depending on what the "doSomething" method does you could get unexpected results.  I recommend setting up a File listener to detect your property changes and then refresh a Spring Context to recreate your beans.  An example of the property file refresh could be found here: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/reloadedable-properties-file-spring-using-apache-commons-configuration/